# How to solve ' undefined reference ' error when executed 'make' command and get the final output file

Tags: c, makefile, .so

I am new to the concept of `.so` files and makefiles, so please guide me what's wrong in my makefile, when I am executing the `make` command, it creates `.so` files but it gives and error saying

```
/usr/bin/ld: subfolder/srcs/file_name.so: undefined reference to `function_name'
```

Before showing you the makefile, I would like to give you a glimpse of my folder structure

```
main_folder/  
├── Makefile  
├── main.c  
├── main.so  
├── subfolder/  
│   ├── includes  
│   |   └─ all required .h files  
│   |  srcs  
│   |   └─ all required .c files   
│   └─  ...  
└── ...
```

Now my makefile looks like this:

```
APP := Test_app
APP_INSTALL_DIR ?= /home

SRCS := main.c
SRCS += $(wildcard subfolder/srcs/*.c)

INCS := $(wildcard subfolder/includes/*.h)

OBJS := $(SRCS:.c=.o)
SOS := $(OBJS:.o=.so)

CFLAGS := -I /usr/lib 

LIBS += -L -lpq -ldl -Wl,-rpath

all: $(APP)

%.o: %.c $(INCS) Makefile
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $(CFLAGS) $<

%.so: %.o Makefile
    $(CC) -shared -o $@ $< $(LIBS)

$(APP): $(SOS) Makefile
    $(CC) -o $(APP) $(SOS) $(LIBS)

install: $(APP)
    cp -rv $(APP) $(APP_INSTALL_DIR)

clean:
    rm -rf $(OBJS) $(APP) $(SOS)
```

I am not getting what I'm missing and where.

Comment: It means `file_name.so` calls `function_name` but you didn't link the .so with a suitable implementation of that function.  There isn't enough information to help you though.

Comment: Make sure you mark non-file targets with .PHONY (all, install, clean)

Comment: @AllanWind how would i link the files to it and i'll use .PHONY

Comment: You need to create a [mre], i.e. strip everything that is not relevant so we can reproduce the problem.

Comment: `%.so: %.o` says create a .so from a .o but it seems you have other dependencies.  Perhaps you want all the .o should be linked into a .so? `libbar.so: $(OBJS)` then refine the rule to `$^`.

Comment: Why are you making a shared object out of every object? This is not how shared libraries are normally built.

Comment: Btw, I rarely use variables of files and just express the dependency directly.  `all: Test_App`,  `Test_app: libfu.so`. make has a catalog of rules so I don't usually do the `%.o` rule for example.  This means you end up with just a few lines with your non-file targets and the actual dependencies.  Also, I don't recall ever seeing Makefile as a dependency.  If you mess with the build system just `make clean; make`

Comment: You haven't told us anything about your project but `main.so` looks wrong to me (if nothing else it's a bad name).  For libraries on Linux you probably want `CFLAGS = -fPIC`

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI since our code files are not encrypted. It's a R&D for encrypting and running our application only through .so files, so i have been creating .so files for every source file.

Comment: @AllanWind I'm working on video analytics using deepstream as a framework. I'm building %.o just to keep track of what I'm doing since I'm to this concept and Makefile being the dependency didn't give me error till now, if i remove it then it gives me error.

Comment: What error are you getting if you remove the Makefile dependency?

Comment: It makes no sense to create a .so file for each .o file, encrypted or not.

Comment: It might not make sense even to build an .so at all.  Do you intend to provide for other applications to dynamically link those functions?  Otherwise, it would be cleaner and simpler to just link the .o files directly into the executable.

Comment: @JohnBollinger yes i intend to build an application with those .so files.

Comment: Thanks to all the help and support. I have overcome the problem. Thank you

Comment: @BasavarajKittali, the question was not whether you intend to build *an* application.  It was whether you intend to build *other* applications with the same library, too.  That is, *more than one* application that uses it.  But since you've found a resolution that satisfies you, I guess that's moot.

Comment: @JohnBollinger no, i intend to build only one application those libraries.

Comment: Then the question is, again, what is gained by building and linking a separate shared library instead of just building the whole thing as a unified application? You can do it however you want, of course, but from my perspective, you're making things needlessly complicated on multiple levels in exchange for no practical gain.